# jsonResponse return id instead of the object name django

Tags: javascript, html, django

i'm trying to fetch data from jsonResponse into ajax , but in the foreign key field it returns `object_id` instead of the object name

my models.py

```
class Product(models.Model):
    item = models.CharField(max_length=50)

class Item(models.Model):
    item = models.ForeignKey(Product,on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    active = models.BooleanField(active=True)
```

my views.py

```
def alerts(request):
    if request.is_ajax:
        data = Item.objects.filter(active=False).values()
        print(data)
        return JsonResponse({'items':list(data)})
```

#print(data) returns this

> <QuerySet [{'id': 13, 'item_id': 14, 'active': False}]>

i dont know how to return item name instead its id (item_id)

```js
  $(document).ready(function(){
      $('.btn-click').click(function(){
          $.ajax({
              url:'{% url 'maininfo:alerts' %}',
              dataType:'json',
              type:'GET',
              success:function(data){
                var obj = data.items
                var mainObj = data.items;
                var k = '<tbody>'
                for(i = 0;i < data.items.length; i++){
                  k+= '<tr>';
                  k+= '<td>' + mainObj[i]["item_id"] + '</td>';
 '</td>';

                  k+= '</tr>';                  
                }
                k+='</tbody>';
                document.getElementById('tableData').innerHTML = k;
              }

          })
      })
  })
```

```html
        <div x-data="{ dropdownOpen: false }">
          <button @click="dropdownOpen = !dropdownOpen"
            class="relative z-10 block rounded-md text-black p-2 focus:outline-none btn-click">
            <i class="fas fa-bell"></i>
          </button>
      
          <div x-show="dropdownOpen"
            class="absolute left-2 top-10 text-right py-2 w-59 grayBG rounded-md shadow-xl z-20 h-48 overflow-y-scroll ">
            <table cellpadding="2" cellspacing="2" border="0" bgcolor="#dfdfdf" width="40%" align="center">
              <thead>
                  <tr>
                      <th width="30%">deactive items</th>
                  </tr>
              </thead>
                  <tbody id="tableData"></tbody>
              </table>

      
          </div>
        </div>
```

is there something wrong within my json response ? or a better approach to achieve it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can add these to the [**`.values(…)`** [Django-doc]](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/querysets/#values), thus:

```
from django.db.models import F

def alerts(request):
    if request.is_ajax:
        data = Item.objects.filter(active=False).values(
            'id',
            name=F('item__item')
        )
        print(data)
        return JsonResponse({'items':list(data)})
```

But using `.values(…)` is often *not* a good idea, even for JSOn serialization. You can use [*Django's serialization framework*](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/topics/serialization/) or work with the [*Django REST framework* (DRF)](https://www.django-rest-framework.org/). DRF has better tooling to serialize, and make CRUD views.

Comment: i can thank you enough , i appreciate your answers